Angular - how to use a pipe with markdown
Im trying to "pipe" my markdown file so it wont sanitize our inline-style's within my markdown files. Im using angular ngx-markdown (12.0.01).
Markdown component
@Component({
  selector: 'documentation-markdown',
  template: `
    <div class="markdown-padding">
      <markdown [src]="file"></markdown>
    </div>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./markdown.documentation.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class MarkdownDocumentation implements OnInit {

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private _change: ChangeDetectorRef,) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe( (map) => {
      this.file = map.get('file') ?? '';
    });
  }

  private _file: string | undefined = undefined;
  public get file() : string | undefined {
    return this._file;
  }
  public set file(value: string | undefined){
    if( value ) {
      this._file = `assets/markdown/${value}.md`;
    } else {
      this._file = undefined;
    }
    this._change.detectChanges();
  }

}

Markdown file im trying display
| Token             | Value          | Example    | Inheritance    |
|-------------------|----------------|------------|----------------|
| <div><code class="token-name">kite-button-background-color</code></div> | <div class="token-value">#0073d1<br />rgb(0, 115, 209)</div> | <div class="token-example--color" style="background-color: #0073d1; border: 1px solid var(--kite-color-text, #000); border-color: var(--kite-border-color, #d8dde6); border-radius: var(--kite-size-32, 2rem); height: var(--kite-size-32, 2rem); width: var(--kite-size-32, 2rem);"></div> | <ul class="token-inheritance-list" style="list-style:none; margin:0; padding:0;"><li style="margin:0; padding:0;"><code class="token-name">⬇︎ #0073d1</code></li><li style="margin:0; padding:0;"><code class="token-name">⬇︎ kite-color-blue-20</code></li><li style="margin:0; padding:0;"><code class="token-name">⬇︎ kite-color-primary</code></li><li style="margin:0; padding:0;"><code class="token-name">● kite-button-background-color</code></li></ul> |

Sanitation pipe I was told to use to allow inline-styling to be rendered:
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
  name: 'TrustPipe'
})
export class TrustPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer){}
  transform(value: string): SafeHtml {
    return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
  }
}

I have very limited knowledge of markdown in general and im having the hardest of times trying to figure out how to use this pipe so that my inline-styles will show on the page. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

You can set [disableSanitizer]="true" to prevent the component from sanitizing your input (see)

@Pieterjan i should add were stuck on angular 12. So im using ngx-markdown 12.0.1

I fixed the issue by adding:
MarkdownModule.forRoot({ loader: HttpClient, sanitize: SecurityContext.NONE }),

to the app.module
